# How can entropy help in machine learning classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, entropy

I cannot fully grasp why entropy is so important in machine learning classification. I understand the usage in decision trees but I don't see the importance elsewhere. I mean entropy somehow comes up naturally in decision trees but aside from that I don't see the importance at all.

Comment: In statistics mean is really a measure of central tendency, and standard deviation is a measure of tendency of variation. Median, geometric mean, harmonic mean, these are all alternate measures of central tendency. Interquartile range, geometric variance, harmonic variance, or measures of spread. Spread is pretty important. Analysis of variance is about spread. Entropy is a measure of capacity for spread. It can be used in a lot of places.

Comment: Can you give an example where you don't understand its use or significance, so it becomes a proper question? Otherwise it's too broad to answer or comment.

Comment: @gunes I just don't get why for example the cross entropie loss should be good for classification. I understand this whole entropy topic as a measure of uncertainty in a situation. The entropy for a given probability distribution gives me the average information which I would get if I would draw a sample from this distribution. I just don't get how one links this to classification and why the perspective of information gain/uncertainty is reasonable in the situation of classification.

Comment: Calling what they do in classification, cross entropy is a bit of a lie. Soft max is needed to normalize the output (required because everything is done in batches i.e. the stochastic in sgd), what they do after that does nothing more than maximizing the component of the correct classification.